# Pandas: calculation of the number of days when the sum of the durations on that day was more than 30 minutes

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample source:

```
ID      Date              Duration
111     2020-01-01        00:42:23
111     2020-01-01        00:23:23
111     2020-01-02        00:37:22
222     2020-01-02        00:13:08
222     2020-01-03        01:52:11
....
999     2020-01-31        00:15:21
999     2020-01-31        00:52:12
```

I use Pandas and I want to calculate the sum of duration for each day by Date, and calculate how many days in month sum of duration by day > 30 min (group by ID)

Here is what I need to get:

```
ID      Total days when sum of duration by day from each ID > 30 min (per month)
111     2
222     1
.... 
999     5
```

Some like this:

```
    aggregation = {
        'num_days': pd.NamedAgg(column="duration", aggfunc=lambda x: x.sum() > dt.timedelta(minutes=30)),
    }
    total_active = df.groupby('Id').agg(**aggregation)
```

But this is not at all what I need...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df['_duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Duration'], format="%H:%M:%S").dt.hour

df_g = df.groupby('id')['_duration'].sum().reset_index()

# this should yield greater than 30.
df_g = df_g[df_g['_duration'] > 30]
```

[to_dateime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
print(df)

    ID  Date    Duration
0   111 2020-01-01  00:42:23
1   111 2020-01-01  00:23:23
2   111 2020-01-02  00:37:22
3   222 2020-01-02  00:13:08
4   222 2020-01-03  01:52:11
5   999 2020-01-31  00:15:21
6   999 2020-01-31  00:52:12
```

use `pd.Timedelta` to convert the `Duration` column's dtype to `<m8[ns]`:

```
df['Duration'] = df.Duration.apply(pd.Timedelta)
```

and then use `groupby` and `sum`:

```
result = (df.groupby(['ID', "Date"])['Duration'].sum() > "30min").groupby("ID").sum()
```

Output:

```
ID
111    2.0
222    1.0
999    1.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if we are to sum or count. However to meet your output.

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])#Coerce Date to datetime
df['Duration']=pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'], unit='m')#Coerce duration to timedelta
df.set_index(df['Date'], inplace=True)#Set time as index
#Groupby date and id, examine condtiton and sum.
(df.groupby([df.index.date, df.ID])['Duration'].sum()>'30min').groupby('ID').sum()
```